# Does CFSTR() allocate memory?

Tags: c, macos, memory, memory-leaks, core-foundation

I understood the [CFSTR() documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211-CH201-F13893) to indicate that it allocates memory. It can return NULL on failure, and the result is available until the program terminates regardless of whether one calls CFRelease() or drops the reference. It's wrapping the static string, but surely it has to allocate a CFString class struct to do so. And as such it's not appropriate to use in long-running programs.

However, after some pushback on this, I tried the following test program. I don't see the memory footprint in `top` increase. The leaks reported by valgrind don't vary with the loop size. Is there de-duplication happening?

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CFString.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int count = 0;
  int chars = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    CFStringRef str = CFSTR("Goodbye.");
    if (str) {
      count++;
      chars += CFStringGetLength(str);
      // Drop reference!
    }
  }
  printf("%d strings, %d chars\n", count, chars);
  CFStringRef str = CFSTR("Hello, World.");
  CFShowStr(str);
}
```

Another asker [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263285/core-foundation-creates-a-memory-leak-for-every-call-to-cfstr) that CFSTR() *does* leak on Windows. Others say it's like Objective C's `@"String"` literal syntax. The CFString reference mentions needing `-fconstant-cfstrings` on gcc 3.3. So does the macro use a magic compiler extension to create these at build time?

On my MacOS X 10.8.5 machine, CoreFoundation/CFString.h defines CFSTR as `__builtin___CFStringMakeConstantString` *except* on Windows or Linux, where it uses a non-builtin version.

So this seems likely the answer is, "**It doesn't allocate on MacOS X or iOS**".

I don't know how to verify they're actually in the executable as CFStringRefs, but `otool -tV` says:

```
leaq    0x1c8(%rip), %rax ## Objc cfstring ref: @"Goodbye."
```

Instruction pointer relative addressing is some confirmation, and `leaq` means it's not calling anything which could allocate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you discovered, on Apple platforms, `CFSTR` uses a compiler built-in to generate the string at compile time.  It is embedded in the executable as a fully-constructed, usable object; the program doesn't perform any allocation at runtime for `CFSTR`.  The compiler merges duplicate string objects within a single translation unit.  I'm not sure if the linker merges duplicates across object files.

On other platforms, Apple doesn't control the compiler, so it can't use a compiler built-in to embed a constructed object in the executable.  Instead, at runtime, it calls the private library function `__CFStringMakeConstantString`.  You can find the source code of this function in [`CFString.c`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.17/CFString.c).  It keeps a hash table that maps the argument (as a C string) to a `CFString`.  This is the “de-duplication”.  It generally doesn't remove entries from the table.  So each unique C string passed to `CFSTR` will allocate some memory that persists until the program exists.  The memory is accessible by any call to `CFSTR` with the same string argument, so calling it a “leak” is questionable.

Comment: I see, the fallback implementation uses the C string value for the lookup key, so it will de-dup even with non-literal strings. But only if you pass in ASCII!

Comment: It should de-dup for non-ASCII too, but you get a warning in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`CFSTR` is a function-like macro that takes a `const char *` and returns a `CFStringRef`.

```
CFStringRef CFSTR (
    const char *cStr
);
```

As you mention, the documentation provides a few interesting caveats. I would personally treat them as implementation details and manage the `CFStringRef` you get from it as being retained by the create rule, balancing retain/release calls accordingly.

(As far as the reason why it may or may not allocate, I think the compiler has the option to optimize out a `CFSTR()` call by creating an immortal `CFStringRef` just like having `NSString *str = @"MyString!";` would do, but I have no data to support this.)

**EDIT**: As far as de-duplication goes, I wouldn't be surprised if it searches a heap of existing initialized `CFStringRef`s. Again, this should be an implementation detail and shouldn't affect the patterns you use.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. It showed as a function in Dash, probably as a limitation of the viewer. The discussion section is clear on it being a macro.